# Plan for portable Java CRUD application

Tags: java, jdbc, crud

The target computers have either MySQL or SQL Server running on.

1. We get JDBC drivers for MySQL and SQL Server in our project.
2. When the users start the application they select which of the 2 databases to use.
3. One thread handles the GUI CRUD buttons and another handles the CRUD logic.
4. We get everything into .jar file(including the JDBC drivers) and convert it to .exe to be executed on the target computers.

Is this plan correct or it doesn't work this way?

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to an exe? That's not what you should normally do with Java applications. It won't be portable to other operating systems than Windows if you do that.

Comment: Because it's for college project that must be displayed on their computers.

Comment: That still doesn't require you to convert it to a Windows exe. Just package it in a jar file and run it as a jar file.

Comment: You can run JAR-files, too. There's no need for executable packaging.

Comment: you can use a jvm. convert it to a runnable jar

Comment: This works, but the database engine needs to be installed. Maybe an embedded database like java Derby or H2 database might be easier. Using a database as file.

Comment: I think it's requirement for the project(to demonstrate that we know how it is done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just include both the drivers, that's totally ok. As long as you only load one there definitely won't be any problems.
2. You may implement a simple detection of the databases at their standard paths / check if it is already running on the default port. If there's only one database avaiable, just work with that.
3. If you use `Swing`, there's the `SwingWorker` class to encapsulate (long running) CRUD operations.  The gui is managed by the main thread / EDT, there's no need to exactly create 2 threads, if you're doing it right. (Although internally there will be multiple threads, but I'm talking about explicit `Thread` creation here.) Otherwise you would produce them busy wait scenario which could be really cpu consuming.
4. You can produce runnable jar files, which can be double clicked and executed on most systems, there's no need to convert it to exe-files.